# Verificar se input file está preenchido

Tags: php

Estou com uma dificuldade que não estou conseguindo resolver, mesmo sendo uma situação simples. Estou tentando validar um campo *input* `file`, o campo precisa ser preenchido, o que tenho:

Formulário:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="frmDoc" method="post">

<legend>Selecione o PDF</legend>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Arquivo</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <input name="Arquivo" type="file" class="btn btn-default" id="Arquivo">
    <p class="help-block"> Extensão permitida <strong>PDF</strong>. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tentativa de validação:

```
if (!isset($_FILES)):
    $retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => ' Informe o arquivo para Upload');
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
endif;
```

O *script* está sendo executado mesmo sem informar o arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
if ($_FILES['Arquivo']['error'] == 4):
    $retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => ' Informe o arquivo para Upload');
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
endif;
```

O problema estava na verificação, pois `isset($_FILES)` é sempre verdade, `$_FILES` existe sempre, mesmo que esteja vazio. O que fiz em cima foi verificar se dentro dentro desse array existe o `Arquivo` definido no form.

[Mais sobre erros de upload](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Também aconselho a fazer uma verificação do lado cliente, com `required`:

```
<input name="Arquivo" type="file" class="btn btn-default" id="Arquivo" required>
```

Comment: Olá @Miguel, agora mesmo informando o arquivo a mensagem de erro está sendo exibida, valeu pela dica.

Comment: Como @adventistapr ? Se fizezeres o upload ficas com a mensagem de erro? O campo file chama-se, tem o `name` "Arquivo" certo? Não está a fazer bem o esperado?

Comment: Peço desculpa @adventistapr, foi um lapso meu, coloquei de maneira correta agora

Comment: Então, fiz a alteração como você indicou e o estranho é isso, mesmo com o campo preenchido minha mensagem é exibida, o campo do input está correto.

Comment: @adventistapr , no form não devia post? `...method='POST'`

Comment: Corrigido @adventistapr , desculpa, foi erro meu

Answer (score 1):

Você pode verificar o tamanho do arquivo.
Se for igual a 0 é porquê não teve upload.

```
if ($_FILES['Arquivo']['size'] == 0)
```